# Compile is really slow for a solution with many projects

Tags: vb6

I have a VB6 solution with about 15 projects.  The compile time and build time runs into minutes.  (Usually around 6 minutes)

Any ideas?

Comment: How many minutes? One or two, or like 20?

Comment: hi @mclaassen. I updated the question with 6 mins

Comment: Modern machines are pretty astonishing in terms of compute and memory caching.  What are you running this on?

Comment: VB6 doesn't natively support intermediate compiles and requires a full rebuild each time. If you have multiple projects, you can try just rebuilding the one that have changed.

Comment: I seem to get into DLL hell very easily if i dont compile all the projects all the time.

Comment: You may want to look at binary compatability. This will allow you to recompile only the ones that have changed without breaking pre compiled projects (unless you actually change the interface)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Create new virtual (XP) machine for compiling (install only needed software),
- refresh your virtual machine every month or so (every compile pollutes registry),
- disable any kind of antiviruses there (and probably on host PC),
- use fastest available computer (like i5 + SSD + 4GB, cores count doesn't matter).

This way you could achieve 2-3 minutes or so. No way to reach 2-3 seconds.

And you don't have to compile entire solution every time - make your components binary (or at least project) compatible and compile only required projects.

Comment: SSD makes a big difference for VB6 compiles -- all the object files are written to disk and read back again

Comment: I'd take it one step further and take the hard drive out of the equation all together.  In the past, I've installed a RAM Disk and placed VB6 on there - that worked pretty well for large projects.

Comment: RAM disk seems good idea, haven't tried myself (yet). Currently we're using virtual PC guests (XP usually) on powerful host machine; when our build process needs some performance boost again, we will try RAM disk for sure.

Comment: I am also asking if there is a way to clean out the registry http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888860/compile-is-really-slow-for-a-solution-with-many-projects

Comment: @kirsteng: The reference should be http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16921672/how-can-i-clean-my-registry-from-vb6-compile-entries.

Comment: Hi @Arvo  do you have more information about "every compile polluting the registry" ?

Comment: @kirsten g: if you have any classes, controls or forms used in your VB6 project, then VB6 rewrites registration info for these components while compiling; this operation tends to grow registry. If you run your project group under VB6, this is even worse - VB6 reregisters all classes to point to VB6 and after ending program, registers them back to corresponging DLL or OCX or ActiveX EXE files.
There are registry compacting programs, which should be able to compact registry files at reboot - but restoring clean virtual machine is much easier.

Comment: How do I find this information in the registry? What am I searching for?

Comment: All your COM objects registration info - ProgIDs, Typelibs etc etc. Note that deleting this info from regsitry does not shrink registry size!

Answer (score 0):

One thing to try is to delete all `.vbw` files before compiling.

This file is the workspace file that remembers which form you had open last etc. You can safely delete it and it will be recreated for you.

This may make a difference if you have a lot of forms in your project.

Comment: That only effects which windows are opened and where when editing the project. There is no other state saved in that file.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled Visual Studio 2010 and am building in around 75 seconds!