# How can I clean my registry from VB6 compile entries?

Tags: vb6, registry

Arvo's answer to my question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888860/compile-is-really-slow-for-a-solution-with-many-projects), where he points out that every compile polutes the registry prompts me to ask
Is there a way I can clean out my registry of entries created by compile and builds?

Comment: What registry entries you mean? There is no information in referenced question.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. I will also look for more information on what actually happens.

Comment: Ask Arvo in a comment to the linked question's answer to edit and explain what that means, because there's no information (or way to verify that it's actually true). If you don't know for sure what entries are there and what they are, how do you expect us to help you delete them? You accepted the answer as correct; you should verify that it is before doing so.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VB6 only really "leaks" COM registration entries when you frequently change COM interfaces of a library. There is no autmated way within VB6 to clean these up, unless you go to a 3rd party registry cleaner (not recomended).

You can reduce the initial problem by being VERY careful when compiling COM objects and make sure you maintain binary compatability, and update you compatable library as soon as you add any new classes or methods, or unregister the old DLL before each compile.